# How can my return statement not omit number 0 in this situation in python

Tags: python, function, return, zero

I have made this function that is meant to print each digit of a number one-by-one without using loops (comprehensions are not included).I have done a good job thus
far the only thing im missing is that my return statement completely ommits the number 0
(ex.print_digits(2019) = 2
1
9)

```
def print_digits(x):
    ver = [u for u in str(x)] 
    if x < 10:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(ver[0])
        ver.pop(0)
        a_string = "".join(ver)
        inter = int(a_string)
        return print_digits(inter)
```

Comment: Do not use recursion for this. Use `else: print(ver, sep="\n")` to print each character on its own line - the whole function is in essence: `def print_digits(num): print(*str(num),sep="\n")`

Answer (score 2):

After

```
ver.pop(0)
```

`a_string = '019'`, so

```
inter = int(a_string)
```

evaluates to `19`.

You can still print 0 by adding

```
if a_string[0] == '0':
    print(0)
```

between

```
a_string = "".join(ver)
```

and

```
inter = int(a_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Modified version

```py
def print_digits(x):
    ver = [u for u in str(x)]

    # change 'x' to 'int' before comparison
    if int(x) < 10: 
        print(x)
    else:
        ver.pop(0)
        a_string = "".join(ver)
       
        # comment this line. Now the function argument can be string.
        # inter = int(a_string)
        
        # give 'a_string' (instead of 'inter') to the function
        return print_digits(a_string)
print_digits(2019)
```

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner for 'merge request' :p

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid recursion altogether using something like:

```
def print_digits(x):
    print("\n".join(list(str(x))))
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Patrick, the idea is splitting the str representation of the number and rejoin according to some separator - in this case `\n`. What the point of it is... I think it is a question for OP

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because when the number "09" gets converted to integer it changes to 9 and when the condition x<10 gets checked it turns out to be true. I have fixed your code.

```
def print_digits(x):
  ver = [u for u in str(x)]
  if int(x) < 10 and x[0]!="0":
  
      print(x)
  else:
      print(ver[0])
      ver.pop(0)

  a_string = "".join(ver)
  return print_digits(a_string)
```